# Silverlight 4 Nested Navigation Frame Communication

Tags: c#, silverlight, navigation

Hey everyone, this one is really stumping us and we can't find anyone else having the same issue.

We have a Silverlight business application, with nested Navigation Frames. Within the nested frame we have some User Controls which we want to use to make the outer Navigation Frame navigate to a new page.

How do get access up to the outermost Navigation Frame, from the lowest level user controls?

Thanks for any help you can give.

Martyn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We eventually came across the Prism framework and have utilised the DelegateCommand functionaltiy to achieve our goal.